# How to keep subview on UITableViewCell

Tags: ios, swift, xcode

When the user taps the accessory view, the profile image in the UITableViewCell gets darkened by a black view that gets added on as a subview.

Here is what the cell looks like with the black subview:

[image]

Here's the issue: When I tap on another cell, the subview gets removed from the first cell and added to the second:

[image]

I would like to keep the subview for all cells that have been tapped.

Here is the code in which I handle that functionality:

```
 self!.profileImageBlackView.cornerRadius = cell.followUserImage.frame.height/2
 self!.profileImageBlackView.frame = cell.followUserImage.frame
 cell.followUserImage.addSubview(self!.profileImageBlackView)
 cell.followButton.hidden = false
```

For some reason, the follow button gets added to both cells, but the "profileImageBlackView" gets moved from cell to cell depending upon which one was activated.

Comment: `profileImageBlackView` should belong to the UITableViewCell subclass and you should just hide/unhide it in `cellForRow` method.

Comment: Also it seems like `profileImageBlackView` is not a `UIView`, but rather a `CALayer` so call it accordingly

Comment: Is this the default highlight behavior of UITableViewCell? If so, enable multi selection in the table.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot display the same view in different cells. If you add the view to another cell it's removed from the first one. You must create a separate view for each cell.